attempted to navigate before mounting the root layout component. ensure the root layout component is rendering a slot, or other navigator
my app/index.js
is just a loader
app/_layout.tsx
const MainLayout = () => {
  const [initializing, setInitializing] = useState(true);
  const {isAuthenticated} = useAuth();
  const segment = useSegments();
  const router = useRouter();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof isAuthenticated === 'undefined') return;
    const inApp = segment[0] == '(auth)';
    if (isAuthenticated && !inApp) {
      router.replace('/(auth)/home');
  
    }
    else if (isAuthenticated == false) {
      router.replace('/login');
    }
      setInitializing(false);
  }, [isAuthenticated]);
  return <Slot />
}
export default function RootLayout() {
  return(
    <AuthContextProvider> 
      <MainLayout />
    </AuthContextProvider>


  )}

the issue occurs only if there is a user and the app wants to navigate to home. if there is no user the login page shows with out any issue.
